# Can I have unity space saving features in gnome?

Tags: unity, gnome, gnome-shell

I really liked unity. Because unity saves lot of space in bars. Current gnome-shell has lot of wasted space in bars. System information bar (weekday, clock etc.), program's titlebar and program's menubar. Unity merges them together in single titlebar which makes more usable space in program's window.

Question is can I merge these bars into single bar just like unity7 does?
If it possible how?

gnome-shell screenshots.
[image: chromium browser in gnome-shell]
[image: terminal in gnome-shell]

unity7 screenshots.

[image: chromium browser in unity]
[image: terminal in unity7]

And unity7's space saving menu

[image: unity7's space saving menu]

Comment: Can just install unity desktop and have it back.  It does not have problems installing on a gnome system.

Comment: To confirm previous comment Unity Desktop works on all Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Have added unity desktop on 18.04, 19.04 and 19.10.  Have not had any problems including any doubling of apps.  I would not recommend adding other desktops since I have not tried them.

Comment: @crip659 thanks. That's what I'm doing until today. But I'm curious. Unity7 stopped development, Unity8 has no stable version. I'm experimenting on gnome-shell. I'm finding answer for me the question that Do I need to move on or stay with unity7.

Comment: Maybe I need to look around KDE.

Comment: Development might have stopped, but it is still supported at least till 2021.  https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-beaver-unity.html